# Python Scripting in TIBCO Spotfire to show custom Messages

Tags: python, visualization, data-visualization, ironpython, spotfire

I am loading a data table on demand and have linked it to markings in a previous tab. The Data table look like:

```
  ID        Values
  1         365
  2         65
  3         32
  3         125
  4         74
  5         98
  6         107
```

I want to limit the data that is brought into this new visualization based on distinct count of ID.

I am currently doing it using
"Limit Data by Expression" section in the properties.
Where my expression is

```
UniqueCount(ID) <= 1000
```

This works perfectly, however, I'd also like it to display a message like
"Too many IDs selected. Max Limit is 1000"

I was thinking of doing this using a property control where the property control triggers an iron python script. Any suggestions on how to write that script ?

Comment: This is definitely doable with a cursor object, but since it will have to parse through every marked row of the data table, I do not suggest it for large data sets, because it will freeze for a while to process.

Depending on the size, it may be preferable to add a data table that only gets the distinct count of IDs in your selected data, and have the cursor read through that data set (which would only be 1 row).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One work-around would be use of a small Text Area on the page (perhaps as a header).  You can `Insert Dynamic Item` -> Calculated Value or Icon and have it perform a count or unique count based on marking (selection).  For example, once the Count(ID) is > 1000, the text can change to red, or the icon can change color.  This is a processing-light alternative which won't necessarily create a pop-up, but can still provide instant notification to a user that too many rows have been selected.

Edit below:

```
<!-- Invisible span to contain a copy of your value -->
<span style="display:none;" id="stores-my-count"><span id="seek-ender"></span></span>


\\Javascript below to grab dynamic item element's value and put it into a span
\\To be executed every time the dynamic value changes
$("#DynamicItemSpotfireID").onchange = function() {
  var myCount = $("#DynamicItemSpotfireID").text();
  $("#stores-my-count").append(myCount);
}

#IronPython script to locate the value placed into the span by the JS above
#and put only that portion of the page's HTML (only the value) into a document property
parentSpan = '<span id="stores-my-count">'
endingSpan = '<span id="seek-ender">'
startingHTML = myTextArea.As[VisualContent]().HtmlContent
startVal = startingHTML.find(parentSpan, startingIndex, endingIndex) + len(parentSpan)
endVal = startingHTML.find(endingSpan, startingIndex, endingIndex)
Document.Properties["myMarkingCount"] = startingHTML[startVal:endVal]
```

I haven't tested most of this code and I provide it as a place to start thinking about the problem, rather than a turnkey solution.  Hopefully it works with only minor tweaking necessary.

Comment: Thanks! This was helpful. A quick follow up. Is there a way to pass the value of a dynamic item into a custom expression or property control ?

Comment: I wasn't sure at first and was ready to write, "unfortunately no," but after thinking about it for a while, there is a convoluted workaround!you could write an IronPython script

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize hitting [Enter] would immediately commit my comment.

You could first write some JavaScript to get the value out of the dynamic item, and then write an IronPython script to seek out the value within your Text Area.  Unfortunately, an example of the code (not even the full answer) would exceed the comment box limits.